# Excel small mistake in function

Tags: excel, function

I'm having a small problem with my formula in excel. I got a long list with IDs from different people numbered from 1 to 20535 for which I want to calculate the portfolio return. One ID has multiple lines so the ID is repeated over multiple lines depending on their number of investments.

*This is the formula* (it's working perfectly except for the bold)

> =IF(**B3=1**;SUMIF($B$2:$B$357553;V3;$D$2:$D$357553);B4=B3+1)+IF(**B3=1**;SUMIF($G$2:$G$187396;V3;$I$2:$I$187396);B4=B3+1)+IF(**B3=1**;SUMIF($M$2:$M$544950;V3;$O$2:$O$544950);B4=B3+1)+IF(**B3=1**;SUMIF($R$2:$R$131523;V3;$T$2:$T$131523);B4=B3+1)

The only mistake is the part in bold. Once I get to the second person (so the second ID) it stops as the condition is not met anymore. How can I make it run past the first person? So untill ID 20535.

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A picture would be nice. I don't think I can understand your question (or rather, what's causing the problem) just by looking at the formula like that. One thing though, `B4=B3+1` returns TRUE or FALSE after comparing `B4` and `B3+1` and does not actually put `B3+1` in cell B4.

Comment: Sadly stackoverflow does not allow me to post a picture

Comment: [IMG]http://i57.tinypic.com/2n1wbwz.png[/IMG]

Comment: You can see in row 8 that the b column goes from 1 to 2 so my formula stops working. However if I can find a way to for example say B2=1, B9=2 etc automatically would fix my problem

Comment: So, in row 8, you want to have `B8=1` but in row 9, you want to have `B9=2`, is that right?

Comment: yes and so on so row 30 would be b30=3. Problem is this keeps going untill 20535 and the row number is not identical for the investors

Comment: But that means that everytime, you want to have a `true` in the `IF` function, right? Why not just add the `SUMIF` then? By that, I mean `=SUMIF($B$2:$B$357553;V2;$D$2:$D$357553)+SUMIF($G$2:$G$187396;V2;$I$2:$I$187396)+SUMIF($M$2:$M$544950;V2;$O$2:$O$544950)+SUMIF($R$2:$R$131523;V2;$T$2:$T$131523)` in row 2 and copied down.

Comment: I tried but something is still wrong with it.
=IF(B2=1;SUMIF($B$2:$B$357553;V2;$D$2:$D$357553);SUMIF($B$2:$B$357553;V3;$D$2:$D$357553)+IF(B2=1;SUMIF($G$2:$G$187396;V2;$I$2:$I$187396);SUMIF($G$2:$G$187396;V3;$I$2:$I$187396)+IF(B2=1;SUMIF($M$2:$M$544950;V2;$O$2:$O$544950);SUMIF($M$2:$M$544950;V3;$O$2:$O$544950)+IF(B2=1;SUMIF($R$2:$R$131523;V2;$T$2:$T$131523);SUMIF($R$2:$R$131523;V3;$T$2:$T$131523)))))

Comment: So where in the formula do I add this?

Comment: It's not working. But it's probably because your missing a part of the excel file. The other side [IMG]http://i59.tinypic.com/2emn7yb.png[/IMG]

Comment: Yea, I was afraid of that. Could you type the formula I gave from scratch and _not_ copy paste? The formula above is split on two lines and that's what causing the error.

Comment: Oh my god it's working thank you so much! Why can't I give you an upvote? I don't see that check mark box anywhere

Comment: I had the feeling it would. I'll put that as answer then :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you just want the `TRUE` part of the `IF` each time, just remove the `IF` and use the `SUMIF`s:

```
=SUMIF($B$2:$B$357553;V2;$D$2:$D$357553)+SUMIF($G$2:$G$187396;V2;$I$2:$I$187396‌​)+SUMIF($M$2:$M$544950;V2;$O$2:$O$544950)+SUMIF($R$2:$R$131523;V2;$T$2:$T$131523)‌​
```

Put the above in row 2 and copy down. That should do it.